# Who to scroll Table view in horizontal and vertical direction in swift 5

Tags: swift, scroll, horizontalscrollview

I want this table view with vertical and horizontal scroll and top header also move along with it . for eg when we scroll left to right header + row moves at same time.

As show in the image below these value are coming from Api (header part is done manually).

[image: Tableview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this examples :

[1]try this [link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView)! , its same behaviour like spreadshit as you mentioned in question image
[2][KEZCollectionViewTableLayout](https://github.com/ketzusaka/KEZCollectionViewTableLayout)

[3][MMSpreadsheetView](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMSpreadsheetView)

[4][DRCollectionViewTableLayout-iOS](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCollectionViewTableLayout-iOS)